# Why is WorkContext.CurrentUser always null?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm working on an Orhcard module and I need to get the current user's ID. I've tried everything I could find on google, but nothing has worked. CurrentUser is just always null. Here are the latest things I've tried

```
public MyWidgetDriver(IWidgetService widgetService, 
            IAuthenticationService authenticationService,RequestContext requestContext,
            IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor, IOrchardServices orchSvc)
        {

            var a = authenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser();
            var b = orchSvc.WorkContext.CurrentUser;
            var c = workContextAccessor.GetContext().CurrentUser;

        }
```

a,b & c are all null. I can get the user's name from the HttpContext.User but I need the ID. the user is logged in. I've tried various accounts and account types. I can see the other parts that work with the user are working and capable of showing the user's name via the WorkContext.

What am I missing?

Comment: `WorkContext.CurrentUser` is the method to use. If it doesn't work, it means that you are looking at a time when it's not yet known.

Comment: Avoid putting any logic more complex than simple field assignments in ctors of classes that are instantiated via DI. Any error there will most likely blow the whole site up. But even if it doesn't - it will slow down the dependency resolving process. Not to mention that most of the classes will not be fully constructed yet at that point.

Comment: @Piotr it was only for testing the di

Comment: @DustinDavis Cool. Just wanted to make you aware of possible problems. These kinds of issues can be painful to troubleshoot later on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access it from the constructor. You need to actually properly inject those services before using them. So...

```
private readonly IOrchardServices _orchardServices;

public MyWidgetDriver(IOrchardServices orchardServices) {
 _orchardServices = orchardServices;
}

public DriverResult Display(...) {
 var b = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser;
 var id = b.Id;
}
```

Comment: That was it. I keep forgetting Orchard user DI which is why it wasn't working in the constructor. Injected, but not available at that state.